# Express.js doesn't allow more than 6 requests. How do I fix this?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am working on a website where the person has to login first. On login, I make a fetch POST request to an endpoint defined in the server. When I login, and logout 6 consecutive times, i.e. login - logout - login - logout .. at the 6th time, I logout, and can't login again. The server doesn't accept anymore requests from the client until I refresh the browser, and then it works for 6 more times.

I've read that there is a 5 requests limit imposed on HTTP requests that are not consumed, even though many people said this limit has been removed.
I am not using the HTTP module. I am creating my endpoints on the express instance.

Here's a snippet of two of my endpoints:

```
const app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.json(getPost('all'))
})

app.post('/register/:user', async (req, res)=>{
   addUser(req.params.user)

})
```

Can anybody tell me how do I fix this issue? Do I try to increase the number of allowed requests ..? Do I "consume" the requests? How do I do that?

Comment: I'm not too sure, but do you need to respond to the `app.post`, i.e. after `addUser` put something like `res.sendStatus(200);`

Comment: This limit is something that Chrome (and all browsrs) implements, not Express.  A single browser window will not make more than a certain number of simultaneous requests to the same host.  The only way I know of to get around it is to combine requests so you're making fewer requests or to split your requests among multiple hosts.

Comment: Djave is correct.  A problem in your current code is that you aren't sending ANY response to your `/register/user` route, therefore it does not complete and the browser sits there waiting for it to complete until eventually it will timeout.  At least add, `res.send("ok")` to it, but probably you want a more meaningful response sent back.  So, after you've done 6 of these, you now have 6 uncompleted requests in flight, where the browser is waiting for a response.  The browser won't send another one until one of the previous ones finishes.

Comment: @jfriend00 It worked with the `res.sendStatus(200)`. Do I have to do this for every request, including the GET and REMOVE?

Comment: ALL requests must send a response of some kind. If you literally want to send no data back and want to indicate a successful response, then `res.sendStatus(200)` or `res.end()` will do. If you don't send a response, the browser has no way of knowing the request is done so it just sits there with an open TCP socket to your server, still waiting for the answer back from the request. Your GET requests will already send a response because the point of a GET it to retrieve data so you probably already have `res.send()` or `res.json()` or something related that sends a response and ends the request.

Comment: why you not put the username in the post body?

Comment: @jfriend00 Got it. Thanks.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone The sendStatus() works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a **response** to your post request.

```
app.post('/register/:user', async (req, res)=>{
   addUser(req.params.user); // this function doesn't respond to the request
   res.sendStatus(200); // something like this does!
})
```

Comment: I'll be damned, this actually worked. Thanks man. So, do I have to add this to all the other requests, or just the POST one? I have a lot of GET requests and one REMOVE?

Comment: Yes, but I bet almost all of your get requests will already have a response (`res.something(...)`). In your example `res.json`. That `res` bit sends a `res`ponse back to the browser to complete the request. In your case, it was sending json, in mine just a status message to say the response worked.

Comment: Got it. Thank you again.