# Express.js doesn't allow more than 6 requests

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a Flask server that streams image data with the `multipart/x-mixed-replace` header. And the Express server connects to Flask, receives image data, and delivers the image data to the client using the `multipart/x-mixed-replace` header.

server.js

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const streamRouter = require('./routers/stream.js');

const fs = require('fs');
const privateKey = fs.readFileSync(process.env.CERT_PRIVATE_KEY_PATH, 'utf8');
const certificate = fs.readFileSync(process.env.CERT_PEM_PATH, 'utf8');
const ca = fs.readFileSync(process.env.CERT_CHAIN_PATH, 'utf8');
const credentials = {
    key: privateKey,
    cert: certificate,
    ca: ca,
};
    
const https = require('https');
const server = https.createServer(credentials, app);

server.listen(process.env.SERVER_PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${process.env.SERVER_PORT}`);
});
```

stream.js

```js
process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = '0';

const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/api/cctv/:cctvId*?', async (req, res) => {
    const cctvId = req.params.cctvId;
    const port = req.query.port;
    
    res.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame',
        'Connection': 'close',
        'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked',
    });

    let stream = webStream.get(`http://localhost:${port}/image/infer/play/${cctvId}`, function (data) {
        res.write(data);
    });

    res.on('close', () => {
        stream.abort();
    });
});

const webStream = {
    get: function (url, callback) {
        let webClient;

        if (url.startsWith("http://")) {
            webClient = require("http");
        } else if (url.startsWith("https://")) {
            webClient = require("https");
        } else {
            throw "Unsupported protocol.";
        }

        let clientRequest = webClient.get(url, function (res) {
            res.on("data", function (chunk) {
                callback(chunk, {});
            });
        }).on('error', (e) => console.log(`Cannot connect to Flask Server... ${url}`, e));

        return {
            url: url,
            handler: clientRequest,
            on: function (type, listener) {
                clientRequest.on(type, listener);
            },
            abort: function () {
                clientRequest.abort();
            }
        };
    },
};

module.exports = router;
```

The problem is that only up to 6 clients can connect.

Additionally, only 6 connections can be made from different domains or different browsers.

[image]

Even if I modified the server.maxConnection value, the result was the same.

How do I disable connection limit?

Comment: [Express.js doesn't allow more than 6 requests. How do I fix this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69827669/express-js-doesnt-allow-more-than-6-requests-how-do-i-fix-this)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Express.js doesn't allow more than 6 requests. How do I fix this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69827669/express-js-doesnt-allow-more-than-6-requests-how-do-i-fix-this)

Comment: In my case, it was because the number of keep alives allowed in Chrome is 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that this is because the browser only allows up to 6 simultaneous http connections. I had to change the way I stream images.